# Simplify rules in GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I see this kind of syntax for `rules:if` and `rules:when` in GitLab CI/CD pipeline a lot:

```
job:
  script: echo "This job does NOT create double pipelines!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Is that also equivalent to this?

```
job:
  script: echo "This job does NOT create double pipelines!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "push"
    - when: always
```

Answer (score 0):

`rules` mean that job is evaluated in order until the first match.

first rules

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - when: always
```

are equivalent second rules

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "push"
```

but, I recommend using the first rules, because it is easy to know and easy to read.

---

I have a test for their two rules. first, I set the `IS_JOB_ON` variable to `off`, that pipeline only `test job 3` create, and second set `IS_JOB_ON` to `on`, three jobs are created.

- first [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/blob/9e0508912abde30edc8cf276ea08786e8df95480/.gitlab-ci.yml) and [Pipeline](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/582604827)
- second [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/blob/6e4c05e6f4f627e27804ba7dabf52487cd0bb171/.gitlab-ci.yml) and [Pipeline](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/582605208)

sample:

```
variables:
  IS_JOB_ON: 'off'

test job 1:
  script:
    - echo "run job 1"
  rules:
    - if: $IS_JOB_ON == "off"
      when: never
    - when: always 

test job 2:
  script:
    - echo "run job 2"
  rules:
    - if: $IS_JOB_ON != "off"

test job 3:
  script:
    - echo "run job 3 always run"
```